# How to access current_user variable in controller or model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, devise, controller

I have `1:N` relationship between `user` and `post` model. I want to access `user_id` in `post` model. I tried it by accessing `current_user` but it's throwing cannot find `current_user` variable.

My userModel class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :validatable
  has_many :post
  validates_format_of :email, with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
end
```

MyPostModel class:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 before_create :fill_data
 validates_presence_of :name, :message => 'Name field cannot be empty..'

 def fill_data
  self.is_delete = false
  self.user_id = current_user # here I am getting the error
 end
 end
```

MyPostController class

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authenticate_user!
 def index
  @post = Post.all
 end

 def new
  @post = Post.new
 end

def create
 @post = Post.new(post_params)
 if @post.save
  redirect_to action: 'index'
 else
  render 'new'
 end
end
.....
private
 def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:name,:user_id,:is_delete)
 end
end
```

I can access the `before_action :authenticate_user!` in Post controller but not `current_user` in `post model` or `controller`. What I am doing wrong here in `Post.fill_data. self.user_id`?

Rest of the code is working fine and I can see the new entry of `:name and :is_delete` in sqlite3 database (when I am commenting self.user_id line in Post class).

## Edit-1

I already have migration class for `post`

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
     t.string :name
     t.boolean :is_delete
     t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
     t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to add current_user.id in post model using before_create call back. but better to do is use this

In posts_controller.rb

```
def new
  @post = current_user.posts.new
end

def create
  @post = current_user.posts.create(posts_params)
end
```

This will create a post for the current user.

Your fill_data method would be

```
def fill_data
  self.is_delete = false
end
```

Comment: `current_user.posts.build(posts_params)`

Comment: Yes that is also correct. but see difference between build and new/create.

Comment: `current_user.posts(posts_params)` does not create a new post!  It just creates a SELECT query and uses posts_params in the where clause. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 1):

In Rails your models should not be aware of the apps current user or any other state. They only need to know about themselves and the objects they are directly related to.

The controller on the other hand is aware of the current user.

So the proper way to do this would be to remove the `fill_data` callback from Post. And do it in the controller:

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def index
    @post = Post.all
  end

  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to action: 'index'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:name,:user_id,:is_delete)
  end
end
```

You should also set the default for your `is_delete` column in the database instead, but if you want to rock it like a pro use an [enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) instead.

Create a migration `rails g migration AddStateToUsers` and fill it with:

```
class AddStateToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :state, :integer, default: 0
    remove_column :users, :is_delete
    add_index :users, :state
  end
end
```

We then use the rails enum macro to map state to a list of symbols:

```
class Post
  enum state: [:draft, :published, :trashed]
  # ...
end
```

That lets you do `Post.trashed` to get all posts in the trash or `post.trashed?` to check if a specific post is trashed.

notice that I use `trashed` instead of deleted because ActiveRecord has build in `deleted?` methods that we don't want to mess with.

Comment: I already have migration class for post. Please have a look at the Edit section in question. Do I need to create another `ActiveRecord::Migration` ?

Comment: I tried but still controller is not able to recognize `current_user`

Comment: This migration removes the `is_deleted` column and adds a `is_deleted` column. You can edit the original migration but it would require you to roll back first. Do you mean that your controller is throwing a NoMethodError? Or did you not get rid of `before_create :fill_data` in your Post model?

Comment: It is throwing `current_user` is not defined

Comment: Have you installed devise properly?

Comment: Yes, I did because I developed an application for singin and singup process and it's working. Also `before_action :authenticate_user!` works fine

Is there any way to confirm it?

Comment: Devise should automatically create a `current_user` helper method which should be availble in your controllers.